# Selects returning different tables based on condition in other table in Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

Idea is that I have a temporary table:

```
Type     | Sources
Invoices | 44,22,11
Billings | 99,90,12,34
```

In my application (apex with interactive reports inside interactive reports) user clicks on one row icon: invoices of billings. In my plsql query I get values **#type#** and **#sources#** as a result (they will be injected with proper value by apex). And I want to achieve something like this:

```
select
    case when #type# = 'Billings'
        then (select from table_billings where table_billings.sources = #sources#)
    when #type# = 'Invoices'
        then (select from table_invoices where table_invoices.sources = #sources#)
```

And I have really huge problem on how to do so, because in, fact my main select is from **NOTHING**, only the inner ones have some tables. On the other hand, I can't use from dual because columns and rows count may vary. Any ideas?

Comment: My advice would be to normalize your table and get rid of that CSV data.  It will make querying and maintenance a nightmare.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Unfortunately this Sources column is generated during groupby and I can't do anything about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If columns may vary then this is not possible in SQL. You have to resolve it at application level. When user clicks billings then select from table_billings otherwise from table_invoices.

However if You could unify common output columns then You can use union, something like::

```
select col1, col2, col3 
  from table_billings
  where #type# = 'Billings' and sources = #sources#
union all
select colA, colB, colC 
  from table_invoices
  where #type# = 'Invoices' and sources = #sources#
```

Output columns from both tables have to be of the same type.

Answer (score 0):

You could have separate interactive reports for Invoices, Billings etc. and conditionally render just the appropriate one for the selected type using a server-side condition of the form "value of page item P1_TYPE is X".

Comment: I couldn't do that because that query was used inside already existing interactive report, in plugin nested reports.